# Get the rank based on the score in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I have a leaderboard page that displays users, scores, and Ranking. I am trying to display the rank based on the user score that is sorted. I have tried a solution I found online, the sort is working fine however the ranking is showing 0 for all users.

```
public class Leaderboard 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
}

private async Task GetContacts()
{
    FireBaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FireBaseHelper();
    Leaderboard = await firebaseHelper.GetUsers();

    Leaderboard.OrderByDescending(item => item.Score).Select((item, i) => new
    {
       item = i,
       Rank = i + 1
    });
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. any idea on how I can fix it?

Comment: Could you provide the input that gives you this behaviour? I can't reproduce the problem you mention - see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VHIrlR).

Comment: By the way, when `Score` is a string, `OrderByDescending` will perform alphanumeric sorting which means `114` is "lower" than `12`.

Comment: @Xerillio I have updated fiddle with the data I am using https://dotnetfiddle.net/m6muf2

Comment: @Xerillio I will make sure to change it to int, thank you

Comment: In the fiddle you linked, it still seems to work as expected (given the alphanumeric sorting), doesn't it? `320` is ranked `2` and `50` is ranked `1`. I'm not sure I understand the problem

Comment: Letting aside the alphanumeric sorting the code you show works as expected. But your solution does not take into account ex aequo results, ie two people having the same score should probably also have the same rank

Comment: @Xerillio I have updated my question with the exact code I am using. I also changed the score datatype but that doesn't seem to be the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think perhaps the problem is you are mixing up which object the `Rank` is on. You might be misunderstanding what `Select((item, i) => new { ... })` does. It creates a **new object** for every item in the collection. It doesn't **update** the items in the collection.

I think what you want to do is use a foreach-loop:

```cs
private async Task GetContacts()
{
    FireBaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FireBaseHelper();
    Leaderboard = await firebaseHelper.GetUsers();

    var nextRank = 1;
    foreach (var user in Leaderboard.OrderByDescending(item => item.Score))
    {
        user.Rank = nextRank++;
    }
}
```

And if you want to take @derpirscher's comment into consideration... if you want two users with the same score to have the same rank:

```cs
private async Task GetContacts()
{
    FireBaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FireBaseHelper();
    Leaderboard = await firebaseHelper.GetUsers();

    var nextRank = 1;
    var orderedGroupedUsers = Leaderboard.GroupBy(item => item.Score)
        .OrderByDescending(group => group.Key);
    foreach (var group in orderedGroupedUsers)
    {
        var groupList = group.ToList();
        foreach (var user in groupList)
        {
            user.Rank = nextRank;
        }
        nextRank += groupList.Count;
        // Or if you don't want to skip ranks when two
        // items have the same Score:
        // nextRank++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your rank calculations are still wrong. If there  are two users with rank 1, there is no rank 2, but the next rank is 3 ...

Comment: @derpirscher Yea, I did think about that. But is that always how ranking is done? Anyway, I'll update the answer with that as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

as
Xerillio
said, you can not sort `string` with `OrderByDescending` change `score` property type to `int` if it is possible.

Comment: To be fair, I didn't say you can't sort because it's a string. The result is just usually different from what you'd expect.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But for the sake of convenience, I said this. Here the goal is to sort numerical scores but they are in the string type. That's why I said. Anyway, you are right. 

Comment: @seyyedmohammadhoseinkashfi  I have changed the datatype of score to int but rank is still showing 0 for all of them

Comment: Alright, it's a minor detail here, but be careful when quoting/paraphrasing people and then using an incorrect quote. Regarding the answer, `string` vs `int` does not seem to be the problem in the question. That can't be the reason `Rank` becomes 0.

Comment: change `Leaderboard.OrderByDescending(item => item.Score).Select((item, i) => new
    {
       item = i,
       Rank = i + 1
    })`  with `Leaderboard = Leaderboard.OrderByDescending(item => item.Score).Select((item, i) => new
    {
       item = i,
       Rank = i + 1
    });`